# Wrong spacing before theorem environment (amsthm)

Tags: theorems, line-spacing, amsthm, setspace

I am using the `amsthm` package to have environment.
I also use  `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` to have 1.5 line spacing.

However, when I use the the theorem environment, the spacing before is not done correctly. It gives me a normal line spacing instead of the 1.5-line spacing.
Lets say I have:

```
First paragraph

Second paragraph

Third paragraph

\begin{theorem} Bla bla. \end{theorem}
```

I get something like this:

> First paragraph
>
> Second paragraph
>
> Third paragraph
>  Theorem 1. Bla bla.

Do you know how I can change this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I actually found out the answer to my question by going the ECM route.

What was causing the problem was that I was using the parskip package with the option parfill, so that paragraphs, instead of starting with a blank indent, would start with no indent but separated by a blank line.
ECM:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % <-- Note this line?
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\begin{document}
First paragraph

Second paragraph

Third paragraph
\begin{theorem}
  1+1=2
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I found out that [I wasn't the first one to have the problem](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/-newtheorem-and-the-parskip-package). The solution is to add:

```
\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@for\theoremstyle:=definition,remark,plain\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname th@\theoremstyle\endcsname{%
            \addtolength\thm@preskip\parskip
            }%
        }
\endgroup
```

in the preamble after calling the amsthm package. It will redefine the theorems environment (or any user-defined environment) by adding the warranted extra space at the beginning. The extra space is not hard-coded , so if you remove the parskip package from your preamble, everything returns to the default spacing: nice!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but what does ECM mean?

Comment: I notice there's still strange spacing with the `proof` environment. Following [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192722/a-problem-with-amsthm-and-positive-parskip), I've noticed that `\begin{proof} \unskip Content \end{proof} \unskip` fixes this.  Any chance of filling out this answer to also make the proof environment bulletproof with the `parskip` package? ;-)

Comment: ECM = Exemple Complet Minimal, which in English is Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Answer (score 2):

I used the following file (test.tex)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % <-- Note this line?
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
First paragraph

Second paragraph

Third paragraph
\begin{theorem}
  1+1=2
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

...and then ran

```
latex test.tex
```

to get a file test.dvi. All spacing was as it should be above and below the theorem environment

Comment: Sorry I lost my good habits of ECM... Will try to replicate (or not) the bug this evening!