# A problem with `amsthm` and positive `\parskip`

Tags: spacing, amsthm, parskip

I want my paragraphs to be separated by some whitespace and not indented.  However, there is way too big a space between end of a theorem and begin of a proof (an MWE follows).  What are my options to fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical
  reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in
  themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
  used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
  Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity,
  since knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things in themselves
  (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a representation
  of time. Our concepts have lying before them the paralogisms of
  natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have lying before them
  the practical employment of our experience.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new version, with redefinition moved to preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}


\let\oldproof\proof
\def\proof{\oldproof\unskip}

\begin{document}


\begin{definition}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical
  reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in
  themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
  used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
  Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity,
  since knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things in themselves
  (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a representation
  of time. Our concepts have lying before them the paralogisms of
  natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have lying before them
  the practical employment of our experience.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately.  This is supposed to be coded in a class released in the wild, for people to use.  No manual hacks like this allowed...

Comment: @mbork OK, hence `\unskip` to definition of `proof`. I will change the answer.

Comment: BTW, I'm looking now at the definition of the `proof` environment, and I'm wondering why that skip appears...  If I had more time (and my TeXbook copy at home;)), I could investigate this.  Maybe tomorrow...

Comment: @mbork I can see, that it is solved, hence I am removing my answer.

Comment: No, better change it as you've written!

Comment: Better yet: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\appto{\proof}{\unskip}`

Comment: @mbork Yes, but `etoolbox` for such a small change? Like using a tank against a moskito. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in the preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  So it was `proof` which introduced the unnecessary skip.  Stupid me, I should have tried something like this...