# KOMA script and amsthm: Space lost before and after theorems

Tags: spacing, theorems, koma-script, paragraphs, amsthm

I am having a problem similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167601/13060) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25346/13060), but without using `parskip`, and only after a recent package update. The MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text before the theorem.

\begin{thm}
    Fun with theorems.
\end{thm}

Some text afterwards.

\end{document}
```

produces the following, certainly wrong spacing:

[image]

The space between the theorem and the preceding and succeeding text has gone. This only happens with `scrartcl`, not with `article`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest (released) version 3.14 of KOMA script, see http://www.komascript.de/release3.14 (in German, search for "scrsize10pt.clo"). **EDIT:** The bug is fixed in the (released and in TeXLive as of 20/01/2015) version 3.15.

One workaround (translated from the linked page) is to add
`\csname @listi\endcsname` after loading a `scr*` document class and after every use of the option `fontsize`.

Alternatively, you can edit the files `scrsize10pt.clo`, `scrsize11pt.clo` and `scrsize12pt.clo` to revert the change in this revision; the relevant bit is at the very end of the file, which should be changed to

```
%%% From File: $Id: scrkernel-paragraphs.dtx 1767 2014-06-26 09:20:18Z kohm $
\@ifundefined{@list@extra}{}{%
  \l@addto@macro{\@listi}{\@list@extra}%
  \let\@listI=\@listi
  \l@addto@macro{\@listii}{\@list@extra}%
  \l@addto@macro{\@listiii}{\@list@extra}%
  \l@addto@macro{\footnotesize}{\protect\add@extra@listi{ftns}}%
  \l@addto@macro{\small}{\protect\add@extra@listi{sml}}%
}
\@listi
\endinput
%%
```

(inserting everything from `\@ifundefined` to `\@listi` before `\endinput`).

Comment: Ok, in the future I'll have a look at "Bekannte Probleme Änderungen" first! Danke.

Comment: It turns out that in a larger document (hard to reproduce with MWE), the problem remains. Is there any possible interference with other packages, or setting other KOMA script options? I cannot think of packages that set `fontsize` by themselves.

Comment: Hard to say, since the `fontsize` mechanism runs pretty deep. I had limited success with the first option, but the second (fixing the `scrsize` files) worked for me.